# convert a string that represents a hex array to a byte array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

New here and very novice so pardon any terminology errors...

I have a string that represents (literally) a hex byte array that I need to convert to a byte array.  for example `string a = "8400081A"` that I need to convert to a byte array of exactly the same `{0x84, 0x00, 0x01, 0x1A}`. (with or without the leading `0x`) I found several answers that claim to do this, but they all seem to convert to this `{132, 0, 8, 26}`...

I'm completely stuck...thanks in advance

Comment: `{132, 0, 8, 26}` is the decimal equivalent of `{0x84, 0x00, 0x01, 0x1A}`.

Comment: `byte` value does not have format assigned. It's just a value. How it's being displayed is up to either IDE (when you use debugger tools to peak the value during debugging) or use code, when it's transformed to string and shown to user.

Comment: ah yes...thank you!  the serial protocol for my hardware shows hex so I figured it needed to be...I should have just tried decimal...because it works!.  lesson learned, thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{132, 0, 8, 26}` is the same as `{0x84, 0x00, 0x08, 0x1A}`, only in decimal notation.

`132 == 0x84` (8*16^1 + 4*16^0 = 132 = 1*10^2 + 3*10^1 + 2*10^0)